Why can’t I assign a requested address InspIRCd? “Reason: Cannot assign requested address”
I want to make an IRC server but when I run ./inspircd start it I get this. I turned off UFW and set up port forwarding, but nothing changes:
Inspire Internet Relay Chat Server, compiled on Jun  8 2024 at 11:06:09
(C) InspIRCd Development Team.

Developers:
    Brain, FrostyCoolSlug, w00t, Om, Special, peavey
    aquanight, psychon, dz, danieldg, jackmcbarn
    Attila

Others:         See /INFO Output
InspIRCd Process ID: 3008


Loading core commands.....................................................

WARNING: Not all your client ports could be bound -- 
starting anyway with 0 of 1 client ports bound.

The following port(s) failed to bind:

1.  Address: iamnotgivingyoumyip:6667   Reason: Cannot assign requested address

Hint: Try using a public IP instead of blank or *
InspIRCd is now running as 'irc.mateiserban.xyz'[001] with 1024 max open sockets


I've not run IRC in eons but dumb question. Is there already an IRC server running and/or is there an instance running already that's taken the port?


What is pocketbase and what does it have to do with inspircd? 2) What IP addresses are specified in the inspircd configuration (<bind> tags), and do those addresses actually belong to this computer?


Sorry, typed wrong thing

No other instances running, bind matches ip.

Specifically, does it match any of the addresses that are shown in ip addr? If you run, for example, ip addr ls to 1.2.3.4 (copy/paste the address), does it show a result?

Try sudo netstat -aptn | grep 6667 to see if some other process holds that port.
